# Shared-memory objects in multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Suppose I have a large in memory numpy array, I have a function `func` that takes in this giant array as input (together with some other parameters). `func` with different parameters can be run in parallel. For example:

```
def func(arr, param):
    # do stuff to arr, param

# build array arr

pool = Pool(processes = 6)
results = [pool.apply_async(func, [arr, param]) for param in all_params]
output = [res.get() for res in results]
```

If I use multiprocessing library, then that giant array will be copied for multiple times into different processes.

Is there a way to let different processes share the same array? This array object is read-only and will never be modified.

What's more complicated, if arr is not an array, but an arbitrary python object, is there a way to share it?

[EDITED]

I read the answer but I am still a bit confused. Since fork() is copy-on-write, we should not invoke any additional cost when spawning new processes in python multiprocessing library. But the following code suggests there is a huge overhead:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import numpy as np; 
import time

def f(arr):
    return len(arr)

t = time.time()
arr = np.arange(10000000)
print "construct array = ", time.time() - t;


pool = Pool(processes = 6)

t = time.time()
res = pool.apply_async(f, [arr,])
res.get()
print "multiprocessing overhead = ", time.time() - t;
```

output (and by the way, the cost increases as the size of the array increases, so I suspect there is still overhead related to memory copying):

```
construct array =  0.0178790092468
multiprocessing overhead =  0.252444982529
```

Why is there such huge overhead, if we didn't copy the array? And what part does the shared memory save me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is shared readonly data copied to different processes for Python multiprocessing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-python-multiprocessing)

Comment: You have looked at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array), right?

Comment: @FrancisAvila is there a way to share not just array, but arbitrary python objects?

Comment: @LevLevitsky I have to ask, is there a way to share not just array, but arbitrary python objects?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1269055/222914) explains nicely why arbitrary Python objects can't be shared.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

If you use an operating system that uses copy-on-write `fork()` semantics (like any common unix), then as long as you never alter your data structure it will be available to all child processes without taking up additional memory.  You will not have to do anything special (except make absolutely sure you don't alter the object).

**The most efficient thing *you* can do for your problem** would be to pack your array into an efficient array structure (using `numpy` or [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html)), place that in shared memory, wrap it with `multiprocessing.Array`, and pass that to your functions. [This answer shows how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5550156/1002469).

If you want a *writeable* shared object, then you will need to wrap it with some kind of synchronization or locking. `multiprocessing` provides [two methods of doing this](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes): one using shared memory (suitable for simple values, arrays, or ctypes) or a `Manager` proxy, where one process holds the memory and a manager arbitrates access to it from other processes (even over a network).

The `Manager` approach can be used with arbitrary Python objects, but will be slower than the equivalent using shared memory because the objects need to be serialized/deserialized and sent between processes.

There are a [wealth of parallel processing libraries and approaches available in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing). `multiprocessing` is an excellent and well rounded library, but if you have special needs perhaps one of the other approaches may be better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Francis. I am still a bit confused so I added another question to my original post. If you can look at it, that would be great.

Comment: Multiprocessing communicates with subprocesses using pickling and message passing, so by including your array as an argument to `apply_async` it is getting serialized and copied. To avoid copying you would need a reference to the object made before calling `apply_async` (and do not include `arr` in the argument list), or wrap in `multiprocessing.Array` and pass that.

Comment: Just to note, on Python fork() actually means copy on access (because just accessing the object will change its ref-count).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny Would it actually copy the entire object, or just the memory page containing its refcount?

Comment: AFAIK, only the memory page containing the refcount (so, 4kb on each object access).

Comment: @FrancisAvila "To avoid copying you would need a reference to the object made before calling `apply_async` (and do not include arr in the argument list)": how would you do that?

Comment: @max Use a closure. The function given to `apply_async` should reference the shared object in scope directly instead of through its arguments.

Comment: @FrancisAvila how do you use a closure? Shouldn't the function that you give to apply_async be pickable? Or this is only a map_async restriction?

Comment: If you want to avoid the copy-on-access problem, use pypy.  Since it's not refcounted, it doesn't suffer from the same refcounting issues.

Answer (score 18):

This is the intended use case for [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), which is a library for parallel and distributed Python. Under the hood, it serializes objects using the [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) data layout (which is a zero-copy format) and stores them in a [shared-memory object store](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/plasma.html) so they can be accessed by multiple processes without creating copies.

The code would look like the following.

```
import numpy as np
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def func(array, param):
    # Do stuff.
    return 1

array = np.ones(10**6)
# Store the array in the shared memory object store once
# so it is not copied multiple times.
array_id = ray.put(array)

result_ids = [func.remote(array_id, i) for i in range(4)]
output = ray.get(result_ids)
```

If you don't call `ray.put` then the array will still be stored in shared memory, but that will be done once per invocation of `func`, which is not what you want.

Note that this will work not only for arrays but **also for objects that contain arrays**, e.g., dictionaries mapping ints to arrays as below.

You can compare the performance of serialization in Ray versus pickle by running the following in IPython.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import ray

ray.init()

x = {i: np.ones(10**7) for i in range(20)}

# Time Ray.
%time x_id = ray.put(x)  # 2.4s
%time new_x = ray.get(x_id)  # 0.00073s

# Time pickle.
%time serialized = pickle.dumps(x)  # 2.6s
%time deserialized = pickle.loads(serialized)  # 1.9s
```

Serialization with Ray is only slightly faster than pickle, but deserialization is 1000x faster because of the use of shared memory (this number will of course depend on the object).

See the [Ray documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest). You can read more about [fast serialization using Ray and Arrow](https://ray-project.github.io/2017/10/15/fast-python-serialization-with-ray-and-arrow.html). Note I'm one of the Ray developers.

Comment: Ray sounds good! But, I've tried using this library before, but unfortunately, I just realized that Ray doesn't support windows. I hope you guys can support windows ASAP. Thank you, developers!

Comment: Ray supports windows and its stable, vc++ runtime must be installed but that is easy, comes with visual studio out of the box.

Comment: Ray currently supports MacOS and Linux. Windows wheels are now available, but Windows support is experimental and under development. - Latest from Ray's website https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Ray supports Windows now :)

Comment: @RobertNishihara I tried loading a list of dictionaries in shared-memory but turns out zero-copy only works for numeric numpy arrays. Is there any way I could use Ray to share this dataset between processes without copying it? I did it with multiprocessing Manager but the reading is way too slow.

Answer (score 17):

I run into the same problem and wrote a little shared-memory utility class to work around it.

I'm using `multiprocessing.RawArray` (lockfree), and also the access to the arrays is not synchronized at all (lockfree), be careful not to shoot your own feet.

With the solution I get speedups by a factor of approx 3 on a quad-core i7.

Here's the code:
Feel free to use and improve it, and please report back any bugs.

```
'''
Created on 14.05.2013

@author: martin
'''

import multiprocessing
import ctypes
import numpy as np

class SharedNumpyMemManagerError(Exception):
    pass

'''
Singleton Pattern
'''
class SharedNumpyMemManager:    

    _initSize = 1024

    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(SharedNumpyMemManager, cls).__new__(
                                cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance        

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        self.cur = 0
        self.cnt = 0
        self.shared_arrays = [None] * SharedNumpyMemManager._initSize

    def __createArray(self, dimensions, ctype=ctypes.c_double):

        self.lock.acquire()

        # double size if necessary
        if (self.cnt >= len(self.shared_arrays)):
            self.shared_arrays = self.shared_arrays + [None] * len(self.shared_arrays)

        # next handle
        self.__getNextFreeHdl()        

        # create array in shared memory segment
        shared_array_base = multiprocessing.RawArray(ctype, np.prod(dimensions))

        # convert to numpy array vie ctypeslib
        self.shared_arrays[self.cur] = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base)

        # do a reshape for correct dimensions            
        # Returns a masked array containing the same data, but with a new shape.
        # The result is a view on the original array
        self.shared_arrays[self.cur] = self.shared_arrays[self.cnt].reshape(dimensions)

        # update cnt
        self.cnt += 1

        self.lock.release()

        # return handle to the shared memory numpy array
        return self.cur

    def __getNextFreeHdl(self):
        orgCur = self.cur
        while self.shared_arrays[self.cur] is not None:
            self.cur = (self.cur + 1) % len(self.shared_arrays)
            if orgCur == self.cur:
                raise SharedNumpyMemManagerError('Max Number of Shared Numpy Arrays Exceeded!')

    def __freeArray(self, hdl):
        self.lock.acquire()
        # set reference to None
        if self.shared_arrays[hdl] is not None: # consider multiple calls to free
            self.shared_arrays[hdl] = None
            self.cnt -= 1
        self.lock.release()

    def __getArray(self, i):
        return self.shared_arrays[i]

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        if not SharedNumpyMemManager._instance:
            SharedNumpyMemManager._instance = SharedNumpyMemManager()
        return SharedNumpyMemManager._instance

    @staticmethod
    def createArray(*args, **kwargs):
        return SharedNumpyMemManager.getInstance().__createArray(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def getArray(*args, **kwargs):
        return SharedNumpyMemManager.getInstance().__getArray(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod    
    def freeArray(*args, **kwargs):
        return SharedNumpyMemManager.getInstance().__freeArray(*args, **kwargs)

# Init Singleton on module load
SharedNumpyMemManager.getInstance()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import timeit

    N_PROC = 8
    INNER_LOOP = 10000
    N = 1000

    def propagate(t):
        i, shm_hdl, evidence = t
        a = SharedNumpyMemManager.getArray(shm_hdl)
        for j in range(INNER_LOOP):
            a[i] = i

    class Parallel_Dummy_PF:

        def __init__(self, N):
            self.N = N
            self.arrayHdl = SharedNumpyMemManager.createArray(self.N, ctype=ctypes.c_double)            
            self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=N_PROC)

        def update_par(self, evidence):
            self.pool.map(propagate, zip(range(self.N), [self.arrayHdl] * self.N, [evidence] * self.N))

        def update_seq(self, evidence):
            for i in range(self.N):
                propagate((i, self.arrayHdl, evidence))

        def getArray(self):
            return SharedNumpyMemManager.getArray(self.arrayHdl)

    def parallelExec():
        pf = Parallel_Dummy_PF(N)
        print(pf.getArray())
        pf.update_par(5)
        print(pf.getArray())

    def sequentialExec():
        pf = Parallel_Dummy_PF(N)
        print(pf.getArray())
        pf.update_seq(5)
        print(pf.getArray())

    t1 = timeit.Timer("sequentialExec()", "from __main__ import sequentialExec")
    t2 = timeit.Timer("parallelExec()", "from __main__ import parallelExec")

    print("Sequential: ", t1.timeit(number=1))    
    print("Parallel: ", t2.timeit(number=1))
```

Comment: Just realized that you have to set up your shared memory arrays before you create the multiprocessing Pool, don't know why yet but it definitly won't work the other way round.

Comment: the reason why is that Multiprocessing pool calls fork() when the Pool is instantiated, so anything after that won't get access to the pointer to any shared mem created afterwards.

Comment: When I tried this code under py35 I got exception in multiprocessing.sharedctypes.py, so I guess this code is for py2 only.

Answer (score 7):

Like Robert Nishihara mentioned, Apache Arrow makes this easy, specifically with the Plasma in-memory object store, which is what Ray is built on.

I made [brain-plasma](https://github.com/russellromney/brain-plasma) specifically for this reason - fast loading and reloading of big objects in a Flask app. It's a shared-memory object namespace for Apache Arrow-serializable objects, including `pickle`'d bytestrings generated by `pickle.dumps(...)`.

The key difference with Apache Ray and Plasma is that it keeps track of object IDs for you. Any processes or threads or programs that are running on locally can share the variables' values by calling the name from any `Brain` object.

```
$ pip install brain-plasma
```

```
$ plasma_store -m 10000000 -s /tmp/plasma

from brain_plasma import Brain
brain = Brain(path='/tmp/plasma/')

brain['a'] = [1]*10000

brain['a']
# >>> [1,1,1,1,...]
```