# Share SciPy Sparse Array Between Process Objects

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I've recently been learning Python multiprocessing, and have run into a roadblock. I have a lerge sparse SciPy array (CSC-format), that I need to share in **read only** format between 5 worker-processes. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721915/shared-memory-objects-in-python-multiprocessing?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing) (numpy-shared), but this seems to be only for dense-types.

How would I share a scipy.sparse.csc_matrix() without copying (or with minimal copying) between 5 multiprocessing Process objects? Even the numpy-shared method seems to require copying the entire array, and even then, I can't just convert a scipy.sparse into a mp.Array(). Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot help you with the multiprocessing part of your question, but a CSC sparse matrix is little more than three numpy arrays. You can instantiate another sparse matrix, `b`, sharing the same memory objects as a sparse matrix, `a`, by doing:

```
import scipy.sparse as sps

b = sps.csc_matrix((a.data, a.indices, a.indptr), shape=a.shape, copy=False)
```

`a.data`, `a.indices` and `a.indptr` are the three numpy arrays you want to share between your processes, if you can do that, then instantiating a sparse matrix in each process will be an inexpensive operation.

Comment: Ah, cool. It won't make copies during the csc_matrix() construction?

Comment: Unless you specify `copy=True` it shouldn't.