# How to create Zarr array from a large stack of npy files?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, dask, zarr

I have a stack of 4 dimensional numpy arrays saved as `.npy` files. Each one is about 1.5 GB and I have 240 files, so about 360 GB total and much larger than memory. I want to combine them into a single Zarr array in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

My first attempt was to initialize a zarr array that is empty in the first dimension, as follows

```py
z = zarr.open(
    gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=<project-name>).get_mapper(<bucket-name>),
    mode='w',
    shape=(0,256,1440,3),
    dtype=np.float32
)
```

then read each 1.5 GB file and `append` it to the array

```py
for fn in filenames:
    z.append(np.load(fn))
```

and this seems to work, but it is **extremely** slow... It looked like it might take multiple days...

I am doing this from a virtual machine on the google cloud platform, so my personal network speed shouldn't be an issue.

Is there an efficient and workable way to accomplish this task? Maybe using `dask` with an intermediate step? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: that's definitely what I'd recommend - dask.array has [`dask.array.from_npy_stack`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.from_npy_stack.html) which should come in handy. the easiest way to do this might be to create a dask.array, then wrap this in an xarray Dataset and write to zarr. but you could do this using zarr directly as well.

Comment: I was looking into the `dask.array.from_npy_stack` but it doesn't work with stacks that you generate yourself. It apparently requires an extra configuration file that dask writes when you use `dask.array.to_npy_stack` and I think it also requires specific file names.

Comment: bummer! in that case you could use the distributed.client, preferably in threaded mode if you're working locally, to map jobs over tiles in parallel. This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72666271/3888719 - you'd have to adapt the example to work with multiple files instead of portions of a large file, but the map_blocks workflow should do the trick I think.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the npy files are all the same shape, the simplest thing that you can do is:

```
z = zarr.open(
    gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=<project-name>).get_mapper(<bucket-name>),
    mode='w',
    shape=(240,256,1440,3),
    dtype=np.float32
)

for i, fn in enumerate(filenames):
    z[i] = np.load(fn)
```

This does not use dask's parallelism, of course, but it does skip the checking and updating of the metadata and any last-chunk operations that append() has to do.

Note that you are using the default compression here, blosc. With this much data, it would be worth your while finding which compression/options work best, and also consider whether you would consider lossy encoding to save bandwidth and storage costs.

Comment: This is helpful. I was hoping to avoid pre-calculating the final size along the 0th dimension, but that's not such a hassle.

Comment: definitely preferable to pre-define your array than to resize everything on each iteration. so if it's not a huge hassle I'd follow mdurant's advice here for sure.

Comment: You can always *over*size your array without problem. Any area without corresponding files in the store are regarded as NaN (or whatever filling value you specify).

Comment: Yes and I learned from the question linked above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72666271/3888719) that you can use `np.load(<filename>, mmap_mode='r').shape[0]` to quickly get a large file's dimensions and sum up the sizes on an axis, which makes it pretty easy.

Comment: Also: `np.lib.format.read_magic(f); np.lib.format.read_array_header_1_0(f)`, which is more explicit and would work for any file-like object, e.g., a remote file opened with fsspec.

Comment: FWIW, properly sizing the array at the beginning instead of using `append` does seem to be helpful, noticeably faster, but I haven't bothered timing anything.