# How to do logging using multiprocessing in Pathos correctly

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, pathos

I have a parallel program. It sequentially reads files, the tasks in each file are split across processes. When the file is done on all processes, next file is loaded, and so on. I want to write log files, such that I have a new log file for each data file. I would like all of my processes to write log info, and that they do not interfere with each other. After reading some posts and the [logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html), I have come up with the following minimal example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
import multiprocessing, pathos
import logging

def task(x):
    thisID = pathos.core.getpid()
    logger.info("Process " + str(thisID) + ": Processing stuff " + x)
    return 1

for iJob in range(3):
    # Create file handler
    fh = logging.FileHandler('log'+str(iJob)+'_pathos.txt')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = pathos.logger(level=logging.DEBUG, handler=fh)

    pool = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool(7)
    results_mp = pool.map(task, list("aalkfnalkgnlkaerngnarngkwlekfwebkwr"))

    logger.removeHandler(fh)

    print(results_mp)
```

No matter what I try all of the output goes to the first log file, the other two are created but stay empty. The alternative implementation using bare `multiprocessing` seems to work fine (see below). The problem is that I require pathos, because it allows me to parallelize some imported libraries, that regular multiprocessing refuses to work with

```
def task(x):
    thisID = multiprocessing.current_process()._identity[0]
    logger.info("Process " + str(thisID) + ": Processing stuff " + x)
    return 1

for iJob in range(3):
    # Create file handler
    fh = logging.FileHandler('log'+str(iJob)+'_pathos.txt')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger("MyLogger")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(7)
    results_mp = pool.map(task, list("aalkfnalkgnlkaerngnarngkwlekfwebkwr"))

    logger.removeHandler(fh)

    print(results_mp)
```

Perhaps it is useful to mention that I run the code from Jupyter notebook. Also, I get somewhat unstable behaviour when I run the same cell twice, deleting the log files inbetween. Sometimes the new log files are all empty

Answer (score 0):

ProcessPool creates new workers that [have their own memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10724332/163668). So you can't / shouldn't access global variables. Pass everything you'll need into `pool.map()`.

This works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
import multiprocessing, pathos
import logging

def task(x, iJob):
    thisID = pathos.core.getpid()
    fh = logging.FileHandler('log'+str(iJob)+'_pathos.txt')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = pathos.logger(level=logging.DEBUG, handler=fh)
    logger.info("Process " + str(thisID) + ": Processing stuff " + x)
    logger.removeHandler(fh)
    return 1

for iJob in range(3):
    # Create file handler

    pool = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool(7)
    input = "aalkfnalkgnlkaerngnarngkwlekfwebkwr"
    results_mp = pool.map(task, list(input), [iJob] * len(input))
    print(results_mp)
```